# Cant add text to javaFX textFlow - How to use task correctly?

Tags: java, javafx, textflow

EDIT:
I dont understand how Im changing the UI from the Task, I using a method form the controller to change the UI, how can I do this ?
Please try using my examples and tell me if I need to add some Info

I'm trying to add text from a Task to a Text flow using a method in the controller class, for some reason the program fails on .getChildren() method .

Call for Spliter in the controller class:

```
btnSplit.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<Event>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(Event event) {
                Thread split = new Thread(new Spliter(custToSplit, Controller.this));
                split.setDaemon(true);
                split.start();

            }
        });
```

class Spliter constractor :

```
public Spliter(File f, Controller c){
        this.c = c;
        this.cust = f;

    }
c.updateHebFlow("Dir created: "+ newDir.getAbsolutePath() , INFO_TEXT);
```

Part of the Controller class :

```
@FXML
    private TextFlow hebFlow;
@Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
assert hebFlow != null : "fx:id=\"hebFlow\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'MainXml.fxml'.";

    public void updateHebFlow(String text,String type){
        normalText = new Text();
        errorText = new Text();
        errorText.setFill(Color.RED);
        infoText = new Text();
        infoText.setFill(Color.BLUE);
        switch(type){
        case(ERROR_TEXT) :
            errorText.setText(text);
            hebFlow.getChildren().addAll(new Text("/n"), errorText);
            break;
        case(INFO_TEXT) :
            infoText.setText(text);
            hebFlow.getChildren().addAll(new Text("/n"), infoText);
            break;
        case(NORMAL_TEXT) :
            normalText.setText(text);
            hebFlow.getChildren().addAll(new Text("/n"), normalText);
            break;
        }
    }   
}
```

The program works fine without the Textflow, it stops at the getChildren() method.
Where is the mistake here?

edit:
thanks to @James_D I forgot to catch exception in the task.
I added to the method call in spliter :

```
try{
c.updateHebFlow("Script by TulTul", INFO_TEXT);
}catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

and I get:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = Thread-4
```

Comment: Does it error out or just stop?

Comment: Can you show the context in which `c.updateHebFlow(...)` is called? Is it part of the `run(...)` method? Do you have any exception handling that would catch it?

Comment: @James_D ohh I forgot to catch exception - add try and catch and I get "Not on FX application thread" > adding to main question

Comment: Sorry but the answers from the other questions dosnt help me understand my problem